# Cant find the characters to a phrase I heard growing up, "Gen Men", used as "totally" or "definitely"

Tags: word-requests

like let's say you're full, you could say
"gen men 没办法吃饭“

I think similarly gen men would be used as 完全

"完全没办法吃饭"

But I can't find the characters for "Gen Men". I think I have the pinyin wrong? does anybody know what I"m talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for the word [根本](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%A0%B9%E6%9C%AC) (gen1 ben3) which means "completely" in your context.

Comment: that's gotta be it! was mishearing grandma all those years ago haha. thanks!

Comment: actually if you don't mind, follow up question, i was talking to my grandparents because i just attempted dumplings. they said they looked bad, "捏得不好", to which I wanted to respond “面团弄得不好，根本没办法捏好", saying that the dough I had wasn't good, so i had no chance to fold the dumplings beautifully.  does 根本work here? i can make a separate thread

Comment: Yes, it works. It can be understood as "there was no way to...".